# Why is it not able to retireve the $course variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is a piece of php/mysqli code where it is displaying a list of courses in a drop down menu:

```
    $courseactive = 1;

    $sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course WHERE CourseActive = ? ORDER BY CourseNo"; 

    $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $sqlstmt->bind_param("i",$courseactive);

    $sqlstmt->execute(); 

    $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

    $courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

    $courseHTML = "";  
    $courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

    $outputcourse = ""; 
    $hiddencourse = ""; 

    while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
    { 
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

    if (isset($_POST['courses']) && ($_POST['courses'] == $course)) {
    $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";
    $hiddencourse .= "<p><input type='hidden' id='hiddencourse' value='". $courseno . " - " . $coursename ."'></p>";
}

    } 

    $courseHTML .= '</select>';
```

Now if you look at the `<option>` tag in the while loop, I have stated that each value for each option will be the Course's Id. The reason I have done this is because I want to use that value in order the find the `CourseId` for the selected course and then INSERT it in the database using this code below which is on a seperate page (`insertmoduletocourse`):

```
$courseid = (isset($_POST['courses'])) ? $_POST['courses'] : '';    

$insertsql = "
INSERT INTO Course_Module
(CourseId)
VALUES
(?)
";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
}                                           

$insert->bind_param("i", $courseid);

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
// Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();
```

But the problem is that instead of inserting the CourseId number in the insert, it is just displaying `0`, meaning that it is failing to retrieve the course ID from the drop down option's value. My question is that why is it failing to retireve this and hence keep inserting 0?

I did an echo for `$course` in `"<option value='".$course."'>"` and it displays the correct Course Id so I do not know why it is failing to retrieve it for the insert?

I am using this ajax function below to navigate to `insertmoduletocourse`:

```
function submitform() {    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertmoduletocourse.php",
        data: $('#detailsForm').serialize(),
        success: function(html){
            $("#targetdiv").html(html);
            $('#targetdiv').show();

        }
     });        
}
```

Below is the form where it contains the drop down menu for the course and the string stating which course was selected from the drop down menu:

```
$moduleForm = "<div class='lt-container'>
<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='moduleForm'>
<p id='warnings'>{$pHTML}</p>
{$outputcourse}
{$hiddencourse}
<p><strong>Add Module</strong></p>
<p><strong>Module:</strong> {$moduleHTML} </p>   
</form>
</div>";
```

Below is the form where it contains the module details:

```
$addmodule = "
<div class='lt-container'>
<form id='detailsForm'>

    <p><strong>Module Details</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='idmodule' name='moduleid' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Module ID:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='nomodule' name='moduleno' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Module Name:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='namemodule' name='modulename' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Credits:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='credits' name='creditsname' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div id='moduleAlert'></div>

    </form>

    <p id='addbtn'><button id='addSubmit'>Add Module</button></p>

    </div>
";
```

Comment: Wow, too much code. Please *debug* a little more yourself. Break it down. Is the HTML output correct? Check in your browser. Is the PHP code correct? Check by hardcoding a value that should work. Is the transport between the browser and PHP correct? Check by `var_dump`ing the received values. Please don't just dump all your code here. You can figure this out yourself.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I though as "s" means string, I thought "i" means integer. is it suppose to be 1 to mean integer for bind param?

Comment: @deceze The html and the ajax is definetly correct, the $course variable is working, but it is just when I want to use it to insert into db is where I got the problem. I think coder1984 has the right idea

Comment: Then please reduce the code to the necessary minimum. *"I've got this value X and this code Y and I get unwanted behavior Z"*. It's hard to tell what's relevant to the question and what's not.

Comment: @Pitchinnate But in this link (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) it says corresponing variables which are interger should be i

Comment: @user1881090 Sorry about that I was thinking PDO not mysqli. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing the form `$('#detailsForm').serialize(),` instead of the one that contains the drop-down menu, which is `moduleForm`.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insertmoduletocourse.php",
    data: data: { detailsForm: $('#detailsForm').serialize(), moduleForm : $('#moduleForm').serialize() },
    success: function(html){
        $("#targetdiv").html(html);
        $('#targetdiv').show();

    }
 });
```

Comment: Ah yes, I can see that, so my question will be that how do I include both forms to be seailized? is it written as `$('#detailsForm, #moduleForm').serialize(),`?

Comment: Nope, send it as a json object like this, `data: { detailsForm: $('#detailsForm').serialize(), moduleForm : $('#moduleForm').serialize() }`